# How to load json file from linux path in html file

Tags: javascript, html, configuration

I am trying to deploy my application from windows to Linux environment. In my application index.html as follows which is loading the json file from windows directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css">

</head>

<body><script src="../Config/myJson.json"></script>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I am trying to load myJson.json file in linux directory /opt/config/myJson.json but it's not working.

Basically I want to read json file from outside the war. my war is deployed in Wildfly.
Could you tell me what am i missing here?

Comment: HTML doesn't have access to disk and files like that. You need a web server that handles file management for you.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you cannot directly access local files unless HTML opened with the File protocol. It is recommended that you use nginx or tomcat as a static file server to access.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. this is how I need to do in my index.html <script href="file:///home/User/myJson.json"></script>